# HTTP ERROR: 503 Google App Engine - Closed

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, yaml, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to run an app on Google app Engine (app is using maven) so I run the following:

```
mvn appengine:update
```

which returns:

```
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31.239 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-12T11:04:35-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/422M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And then

```
mvn appengine:devserver
```

which returns

```
...
[INFO] INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
[INFO] Jan 12, 2017 11:06:05 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
[INFO] INFO: Dev App Server is now running
```

So I think the build is properly updating, also I could deploy it successfully online.

But I still get the error at my_project.appspot.com

[image: ERROR: Server Error]

and locally when I try to run the same app I get (Either running the server with mvn appengine:devserver or running it on eclipse does the same tried both for testing reasons):

[image: HTTP ERROR: 503]

I was guessing maybe my web.xml has a mistake in it but I double checked and compared it to the HelloWorldServlet example or Guest Book example and it looks pretty much the same, here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AdWords</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyApp.adwords_axis.MainApp</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdWords</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Also here's the class I'm trying to call

```
package myApp.adwords_axis;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet(name = "AdWords", value = "/")
public class MainApp extends HttpServlet{
      @Override
      public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      {
      response.setContentType("text/plain");
      try {
        response.getWriter().println("Test");
        //run();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  

      }


    public static void run() throws Exception {
        AdReport ads = new AdReport();
        GenderReport genderReport = new GenderReport();
        CriteriaReport criteriaReport = new CriteriaReport();

        ads.start();
        genderReport.start();
        criteriaReport.start();
    }
    //Add Audience before deploying beta.
}
```

The app.yaml (which was never generated when I did `mvn appengine:update`) that I coppied from the examples and dropped it under src/main/appengine looks like this:

```
runtime: java
env: flex

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
  secure: always  # Require HTTPS

runtime_config:  # Optional
  jdk: openjdk7
  server: jetty9

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved this by dectuple checking my web.xml. I had a typo and broke the whole app.

My package was starting with a Capital Letter in the web.xml, which should not.